# How to implement spinning wheel during a backend job?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a need to implement a spinning wheel during a backend job. I have my backend-job in a separate class.

```
class ViewControllerA: UITableViewController {

  // Code
  var GetBackendRecordObj = GetBackendRecord(initparam:param);

  // CODE TO START ANIMATION (SPINNING WHEEL)  

  self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
  self.activityIndicator.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)
  self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

  // CODE TO CALL THE BACKEND IS IN ANOTHER CLASS         
  GetBackendRecordObj.fetch_record()


}



class GetBackendRecord{

  var transaction_id: String = ""
  var current_email_id: String = ""

  init(initparam: String) {
    self.initparam = initparam

  }

func fetch_record (){

    do{
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            //code
            DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                //code to process response from backend
                // NEED CODE TO STOP ANIMATION (SPINNING WHEEL)THAT WAS STARTED IN VIEWCONTROLLERA
            })
        }
   }
}
```

How can I access the UITableViewcontroller after the backend call is done, so I can stop the animation. OR If there is a better way to start / stop animation when executing a backend-job (in a separate class) please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a completion handler to `fetch_record`:

```
func fetch_record(_ completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
    do{
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            //code
            DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                //code to process response from backend
                completionHandler()
            })
        }
   }
}
```

When calling it in your `ViewController`, you can specify what to do after completion:

```
GetBackendRecordObj.fetch_record() {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: thanks @shallowThought . This worked for me. I don't have status to accept your answer - appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know when the response returns so that you can stop the loader, you need to add a completion handler to the method that makes your internet call.  You should generally have completion handlers on most methods that make internet calls, especially if you need UI things to happen only once you have gotten a response.

So for the `fetchRecord` function:

I have added a completion handler to this call. Preferably you would hand something off here just after `@escaping`(something like a dictionary or an array if it is a JSON response) and then process that response in another method. But if you want the code to process the response in this method with the threading that you've set up here, then I've written it accordingly.

```
func fetch_record(withCompletion comp: @escaping () ->()){
  do{
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        //code
        DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
            //code to process response from backend
            //this tells whatever called this method that it is done 
            comp()
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your view controller when you call `GetBackendRecordObj.fetch_record()`

```
GetBackendRecordObj.fetch_record(withCompletion: { [weak self] () in 
  //when it hits this point, the process is done
  self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of activityIndicator better to use MBProgressHUD.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

To show MBProgressHUD

```
let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
loadingNotification.labelText = "Loading"
```

To hide MBProgressHUD

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
      MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
})
```

You can implement show MBProgressHUD in seperate class from where you initiate back end job and hide code once your back end process finish.